# updated local but unable to push

Tags: git, git-branch, git-push

i am unable to push but my local is already updated

```
git pull origin develop
already up-to-date
```

while pushing

```
 git push origin develop                  
 ! [rejected]        develop -> develop (non-fast-forward)
 error: failed to push some refs to 'xxxxxxx'
 hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its      remote
 hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
 hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
 hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

What is going on ?

Added after edit :

```
git show-branch develop origin/develop :


 ! [develop] Merge branch 'develop' of XXXXX into develop
 ! [origin/develop] Merge branch 'develop' of XXXXX into feature/JavaSDK
 --
 - [origin/develop] Merge branch 'develop' of XXXXX into feature/JavaSDK
 + [origin/develop^2^2] [MPSC-2189]
 + [origin/develop^2^2^] [MPSC-2189]
 + [origin/develop^2^2~2] [MPSC-2189] location page 
 + [origin/develop^2~2] locations and service manager
 + [origin/develop^2^2~4] [MPSC-2189] edit location page
.....
 + [origin/develop~35^2^] [MPSC-2177]
-- [develop] Merge branch 'develop' of XXXXX into develop
```

Comment: have you had a look at the commits in both branches with `git show-branch develop origin/develop`?

Comment: i am new to git im used to svn ,, @user1978011 the command u mentioned gives me a list of all commits done by all team members

Comment: Ok, is the output short enough so that you can post it here? It should be quite helpful for us.

Comment: @user1978011 i added with the question the start and end of the list so you can check the error with the commits in top of the list since they are the new ones .

Comment: Try running `git remote show origin`. Do all branches pull and push where they should?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you do some kind of history re-write (eg. : rebase, rename commit messages etc)?

If yes, and if you are sure `git log`/`gitk` shows the correct commits, then you can do a forced push:

```
git push -f origin develop
```